# Debug in Eclipse, for lazy people

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

When I define Breakpoint in Eclipse I can inspect variables's values by hovering mouse over it. Also I can switch to Debug perspective and perform more advanced tasks, like writing custom expressions and change value of variables.
I'd like to know if is it possible to perform some of these task in window which opened when I hovering mouse over variable? For example to write custom expression to translate Java Calendars object's value to human readable format on the fly, etc.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom formatter that overrides the default `toString()` implementation of a type in Window->Preferences->Java->Debug->Detail Formatters:

[image]